# how do i reposition the view on an iOS browser when the virtual keyboard pops up?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, webkit, mobile-safari

I'm doing a chatroom somewhat simular in style(not really a clone) to iphone sms, however I when used on an actual mobile device the text input gets centered on the screen and zoomed in, making it impractical for those devices. How can I cause the text input to be closer to(or better yet underneath) the virtual keyboard instead of centered in the screen. I don't have any none-ios devices to try this on but I assume simular problems occurs on other webkit mobile browsers.

and for a bonus question, any way to make the keyboard go away when enter is pressed or check for the done button being pressed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

This will prevent zooming in onfocus. Try adding user-scalable=no as well if that doesn't help.

As for hiding the keyboard, all you need to do is force the input to lose focus.

```
element.blur();
```